# How to split image with Swift for OSX

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, cgrect, cgimage

I am splitting a 2880 x 2560 image into two two 1440 x 2560 images. I've been trying to use `CGImageForProposedRect` to do this, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly. Here is what I have so far (to show the playground output, code attached at end):

[image]

But if you notice, even though the CGRects are 1440x2560, `leftImage` and `rightImage` are not. Is that not how `CGImageForProposedRect` works? If not, why does it require a CGRect parameter?

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import CoreGraphics

let image = NSImage(named:"image")
if let image = image {
    var imageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    var imageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)

    var leftImageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/2.0, image.size.height)
    var leftImageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&leftImageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    var leftImage = NSImage(CGImage:leftImageRef!.takeUnretainedValue(), size:NSZeroSize)

    var rightImageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(image.size.width/2.0, 0, image.size.width/2.0, image.size.height)
    var rightImageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&rightImageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    var rightImage = NSImage(CGImage:rightImageRef!.takeUnretainedValue(), size:NSZeroSize)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that replacing

```
var leftImageRef = image.CGImageForProposedRect(&leftImageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
var leftImage = NSImage(CGImage:leftImageRef!.takeUnretainedValue(), size:NSZeroSize)
```

with

```
var leftImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef!.takeUnretainedValue(), leftImageRect)
var leftImage = NSImage(CGImage:leftImageRef, size:NSZeroSize)
```

fixes my problem. However I'm still not sure why, so if anyone has a better explanation I'm open to selecting it as the "Correct Answer".

Thanks!